# Markov chains with drift

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, markov-chains

We consider a Markov process $X$ on a finite set $\mathcal{X} (\neq \emptyset)$. Basically, $X$ is associated with a generator of the following form
\begin{align*}
Af(x)=\lambda(x)\sum_{ y\in \mathcal{X}}\{f(y)-f(x)\}\mu(x,y),\quad x \in \mathcal{X},\quad f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{X}}.
\end{align*}
Here, $\lambda \colon \mathcal{X} \to [0,\infty)$ and $\mu(\cdot,\cdot)\colon \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}\to [0,\infty)$ are nonnegative functions. We assume moreover that $\sum_{y \in \mathcal{X}}\mu(x,y)=1$, $x \in \mathcal{X}$.

In this setting, $X$ is said to be a Markov chain on $\mathcal{X}$.

***My question.***

I would like to consider a situation that a discrete gradient is defined on $\mathcal{X}$. Then, we should be able to study a Markov chain on $\mathcal{X}$ "with drift".

**Has such a Markov chain ever been studied (defined)?** If such a thing exists, what kind of perturbation term does the above generator have?

I would appreciate it if you could give me a concrete example.

Comment: Please define what a Markov chain with drift is (literature, ...). Note that your state space $\cal{X}$ is finite.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Sorry. My question was confusing. In the first place, I want to know if "Markov chains with drift" have been considered (defined) so far.

Comment: Chapman, Airlie. "Advection on graphs." Semi-Autonomous Networks. Springer, Cham, 2015. 3-16.

Comment: @PiyushGrover Thank you for your comment. I will look for the book.

Comment: Can one reformulate your question in the setup of the discrete time chains?

Comment: @RW Thank you for your comment. Well... It may be difficult to give a description of the corresponding generator.

Comment: Dealing with continuous (rather than discrete) time introduces an additional level of technical complexity which is quite often not needed at all, and therefore whenever possible one should look first at the discrete time setup.

Comment: @RW Thank you for your advise. Of course I would be happy if I could find discrete time Markov chains with drift.

Comment: @sharpe the article is freely available here:https://folk.ntnu.no/skoge/prost/proceedings/cdc-ecc-2011/data/papers/2247.pdf

Comment: @PiyushGrover Thank you very much. I was in trouble because I couldn't get the book you taught me right away.